# Does the Euler product for $L(s,\chi_4)$ also converge in the right half of the critical strip?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, euler-product

This question expands on [this one from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327543/does-the-euler-product-for-the-dirichlet-beta-function-converge-for-all-re).

In the literature about Dirichlet $L$-series, I found that their Euler products:

$$L(s, \chi) =\prod_p \bigg(\frac {1}{1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}} \bigg)$$

are typically considered to be only converging for $\Re(s)>1$.

However, there seems to be an exception to this rule since Euler proved that:

$$L(1, \chi_4) =\prod_p \bigg(\frac {p}{p-\chi_4(p)} \bigg)=\prod_p \bigg(\frac {p}{p-\sin\left(\frac{p \,\pi}{2}\right)} \bigg)=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{7}{8}\cdot\frac{11}{12}\cdot\frac{13}{12}\dots=\beta(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

does converge (albeit slowly).

I then decided to explore values for $\Re(s) \lt 1$ and numerical evidence suggests that the Euler-product:

$$\prod_p \bigg(\frac {p^s}{p^s-\sin\left(\frac{p \,\pi}{2}\right)} \bigg)$$

also (slowly) converges in the domain $\frac12 < \Re(s) \le 1$.

**Questions:**

1) Is the Euler product for $L(s,\chi_4)$ the only one known to converge for $s=1$?

2) Does this particular Euler product indeed converge in the right half of the strip?

Thanks.

Comment: The Euler product for every Dirichlet series (for a nonprincipal character) 
converges at $s=1$,
but that's more-or-less equivalent with the Prime Number Theorem in
arithmetic progressions, and in particular Euler's heuristic argument
for $\chi_4$ does not readily yield a rigorous proof for that $L$-function.
Convergence for real part $> 1/2$
is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis for the same $L$-function.
(While I was editing this **ABCDveve** wrote similarly in his/her answer.)

Comment: To see the equivalence that Noam mentions, see Theorem 3.3 (and the two lemmas preceding it) in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/articles/eulerprod.pdf, setting $d = 1$ and $\alpha_{p,1} = \chi(p)$. Note that for infinite products like an Euler product, the term "converges" means "converges and is not $0$." Since nobody has ever proved the $L$-function of a nontrivial Dirichlet character has no zeros in any vertical strip $1-\varepsilon < {\rm Re}(s) < 1$, it is basically hopeless at present to expect anyone to *prove* the Euler product converges at any $s$ with ${\rm Re}(s) < 1$.

Comment: Related question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63714/is-the-euler-product-formula-always-divergent-for-0res1/

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Why is the trivial character corresponding to zeta exception to convergence?

Comment: Good question.  The answer is basically the pole at $s=1$.
The connection with the $L$-function zeros is via the logarithmic derivative
$L'/L$, which is singular when $L$ has either a zero or a pole.
Dirichlet $L$-functions other than the Riemann zeta function
have no poles, so only their zeros affect the analysis; but when you
try to do the same for $\zeta$ you run into the $s=1$ pole before
any zero shows up.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies This appears closely related to prime race modulo 4 (Chebyshev bias). Take $s=0.5001$. For $p$ up to $10^8$ the finite product is $0.960060883...$, while $L(s)=0.667719642658...$. This would mean there are significantly more primes congruent to $3$, but not too much to make the product zero...

Comment: For $p$ up to $10^9$ the finite product is $0.9798542...$ for $s=0.5001$.

Comment: The is is a very late reply,  but in any case,  last year Franca and I submitted a paper to arXiv. that provides an argument for why the EP should converge for Re s > 1/2  *without assuming the RH* (for non-principal characters).     We provided a strategy to prove it,  but could not prove one of the ingredients,  which is that a particular series behaves like a random walk.   So it may not be "hopeless" as KConrad wrote,   though it does still seem difficult.    The reason I think there is some hope is  that random walks are rather generic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By taking the logarithm (or log derivative) of $L(s)$, you get a Dirichlet series whose convergence relates directly to the zeros. Your question about convergence in the right half of the critical strip is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis for $\chi$. Similarly, (conditional) convergence of the Euler product (again as the "Euler sum" after taking the logs) on the 1-line is equivalent to the lack of zeros on this line.

Comment: If $\chi$ is kronecker character it is nonnegative. Let $t=0$. Every term is real greater than one. I don't see how this will converge to the $L$ function (computing a single value above the correct is counterexample).

Comment: @joro: The only character modulo $n$ that is nonnegative is the trivial character modulo $n$.

Comment: @GHfromMO Thank you. My mistake. So why the answer doesn't apply to the trivial character which is zeta AFAICT?

Comment: @joro: Roughly speaking, the reason is the oscillation of $\chi$ (when $\chi$ is nontrivial). More precisely, while $\sum p^{-s}$ over the primes clearly diverges unless $\Re s>1$, the oscillating sum $\sum\chi(p)p^{-s}$ has a chance to converge for smaller values of $\Re s$ assuming the primes are sufficiently well-distributed mod $n$ (where $n$ is the conductor of $\chi$). And, indeed, GRH implies that the latter sum converges for $\Re s>1/2$.

Comment: @joro: Two related posts are http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63714/is-the-euler-product-formula-always-divergent-for-0res1/ and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181241/is-there-a-von-koch-type-theorem-for-the-generalized-riemann-hypothesis

Comment: @Joël: I don't see any contradiction. David Speyer shows that the Euler product for $\zeta(s)$ is divergent when $0<\Re(s)<1$. On the other hand, for a *nontrivial* Dirichlet character $\chi$, the Euler product of $L(s,\chi)$ converges in the half-plane $\Re(s)>1/2$ if and ony if the RH holds for $L(s,\chi)$.

Comment: @Joël: If you want, remove your last two comments, and I will remove mine as well.